# Example for showing that an algebraic set is defined over the base field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

Currently, I am trying to understand Example 1.3.1. from Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*:

Let $K$ be a perfect field and $V$ be an algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^2 = \mathbb{A}^2(\bar{K})$ given by $X^2 - Y^2 = 1$.

> The book says that $V$ is clearly defined over any (perfect) field $K$. However, **my main issue is understanding the definition**.

**My own efforts**:

The book defined an algebraic set $V$ to be **defined over $K$** if its ideal $$I(V) = \{ f \in \bar{K}[X,Y] \, : \, f(P)=0 \: \forall P \in V \}$$
is generated by polynomials in $K[X,Y]$.

Also, $V$ which appears in the description of the set $I(V)$ is by definition given by
$$
V = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{A}(\bar{K}) \: : \: x^2 - y^2 = 1 \}.
$$

If the claim is true, this must mean that $I(V)$ is generated by polynomials in $K[X,Y]$. I also think that $g = X^2-Y^2-1$ generates it which would mean $I(V) = (g) \subseteq \bar{K}[X,Y]$. 
I think this is true but I cannot find a way to convince myself why this equation is true (although it might seem trivial).

Another thing which might be helpful to convince myself through antoher way is the following remark in the book: It says that $V$ is defined over $K$ if and only if $I(V) = I(V/K)\bar{K}[X,Y]$ where
$$
I(V/K) = \{ f \in K[X,Y] \: : \: f(P) = 0 \: \forall P \in V \}  = I(V) \cap K[X,Y].
$$

However, I cannot use this observation to my advantage as well.

It would be really nice if could take your time to explain this probably trivial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that $I(V) = (g)$. There are more elementary arguments, but this is an immediate consequence of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, which says that there is a bijective correspondence between affine subvarieties and radical ideals. $(g)$ is radical, and its vanishing set is $V$, so $I(V) = (g)$.

Comment: Thank you for your response too! I just looked up Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. I understand that the vanishing set of $(g)$ is $V$ because this is how $V$ is defined. How would I show that $(g)$ is radical? I have not worked with radical ideals yet but it looks like it has something to do with showing that $g$ is irreducible over $K[X,Y]$.

Comment: It's even weaker than being irreducible, it just needs to not have any repeated factors. Definition: $I$ is radical if $f^k \in I$ for any $k$ implies $f \in I$. Since polynomial rings over fields are UFD's, you can check that $(g)$ being radical is the same as $g$ not having repeated factors.

Answer (score 0):

All ideals are the kernel of a ring homomorphism and the equation $X^2-Y^2-1=0$ implies that $X^2-Y^2-1$ is in such a kernel, because it is mapped to zero. Since it is the only polynomial equation in the kernel that you're given it generates the ideal, or $I(V)=(g)$ in accordance with your intuition.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I suppose by the kernel of the ring homomorphism you mean the map $K[X,Y] \to K[X,Y]/(g), f \mapsto f+(g)$. In this case, $(g)$ is in the kernel. But I cannot see yet how to make the transition to $I(V)$. Could you please elaborate that?

Comment: @Ribbity Yes, it's exactly the quotient map $f$ used in the definition of $I(V)$. $V$ is the generating set for the kernel, all $P \in V$ with $f(P)=0$ is the full kernel.